# If $f:[0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, then $\{ \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) : \lim_{n \to \infty}(x_n) = \infty \}$ is connected.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function on $\left[0,\infty \right)$. Let $A$ be set of real numbers $a$ that can be expressed as $\lim_{n \to\infty}f(x_{n}) = a$ for some sequence $x_{n}$ in $\left[0,\infty \right)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_{n})=\infty$. Prove that if $A$ contains two distinct real numbers  $a$ and $b$, then $A$ contains the entire interval with endpoints $a$ and $b$.

I tried to do a very similar proof to Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem by taking care of midpoints and I tried to  construct a sequence that converges to arbitrary point in the interval $\left(a,b \right)$. I do not know how to argue exactly to show that $A$ is a closed set. If I can do this I will solve the question.

Comment: You're not trying to show that $A$ is a closed set. You're trying to show that $A$ is a connected set.